# No Support for UnityScript (JavaScript) on 2018.3

Tags: unity

Hey I’ve been working on a project for over 3 years and yesterday I have updated the unity from 2018 to 2018.3 and lost support for JavaScript.
All of my scripts attached to gameobjects are there but not working while playing the game.
I’ve tried the UnityScript to C# website but didn’t work.
I’m a macOS user so couldn’t use the converter tool on git (because it’s been developed only for windows).
I’ll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You should go back to the older version if you don't want to learn C#. Once you've finished the project however, you should switch to it, compilation is a lot faster and support is better.

Comment: But is it possible to use a project that's updated to a newer version of Unity on an old one?

Comment: Depends a little whats in it, but not normally thats why you revert using your source control

Comment: It's also why the updater shows you a dialog reminding you to make a backup copy of your project before updating. That goes double when you're using features that were [deprecated two years ago](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/). Do you have such a backup copy or source control version from before the update to revert to?

Comment: I ended up manually porting the (small number of) old scripts I still needed, which was easier than expected. The API is pretty uniform, so depending on the amount of code a (semi-) manual conversion might be an alternative, if you have no backups (and no friend with a Windows machine).